# Prevent man in the middle (e.g. proxy) server from pretending something it is not

Tags: web-services, proxy, cryptography, man-in-the-middle

I am developing a web service and it is of big importance that I can tell when which end-user is currently executing a request. So, in essence, I need an implicit user (or maybe even better would be, a user's device) identification.

My web service does not require authentication, it is possible that users place a proxy server in between their mobile devices and my web service and route all their traffic through that proxy server. I don't want to forbid users to do that because there may be many reasons but I would like to still know which device is currently connecting.

Some cryptography is needed maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to firstly use HTTPS for the web service. This means the server will authenticate itself to the client, plus that the connection will be both encrypted and authenticated.

Once the server is authenticated to the client and the connection is encrypted and authenticated, you can easily proceed with adding a method to authenticate the client to the server. The most simple way to do that is to include a plain text user id and password in each request. This is safe, exactly because the client knows they will be sent to the right server and because the connection is encrypted.

Well configured proxy servers will allow tunneling of HTTPS traffic. This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The bad thing is that this proxy server might be installed by the user himself to modify the requests and allow the user's devices to pretend as something different. The problem I am solving is different from evil man-in-the-middle because user might be willing to pretend. So I am trying to defend my server in this case.

Edit: after some investigations I came to conclusion that this problem is unsolvable in my case. The best way will be trusting the users by offering them benefits if they willingly identify themselves.

Comment: HTTPS provides end point security. The proxy will not be able to alter HTTPS traffic, but only tunnel it through. That said, if the device does not have its own SSL/TLS implementation there might be other ways for the adversary to tap in to the communication before it gets encrypted. Generally speaking it is an architectural failure to give the adversary access to the very resource you want to keep from him.

Comment: In my case, I do not want to protect anything (protection is implemented using HTTPS indeed). I simply need to have a unique identification of end user. Username and password does not work in this case because many devices are allowed to connect with the same username and password. Sessions cannot be leveraged because it is the stateless service. In our case, user could setup a proxy server with its own trusted certificate and forward the date through it, therefore rendering the identification impossible. Allowing users to benefit from being truthful seems like a good solution so far.

Comment: If the device has its own SSL/TLS implementation, it is sufficient to include a (secret) device id in each request. The device will only send its device id to the server, so this should meet your requirements.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider this option.

Comment: @paulius: If the device has its own SSL/TLS implementation, you can also configure it to only trust certificates signed by _you_ with your own private signing key. Essentially, you'll be acting as your own private CA, and telling the device to only trust that single CA.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen that would not disallow others from gaining access in any way. The way to do that is client authentication (see my answer). With just server authentication, anyone can have access, setting up your own CA would have the only effect that the client cannot verify that your certificate is trusted (in Firefox, this would affect a message box with a warning).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you are trying to allow only a single application access to your web-service. One method of doing this is TLS with client authentication. For this the client (your application) should have it's own private key certificate pair, and the server will only allow access if the ownership of the private key is proven. It uses the exact same PKI as the default verification of the server, only the other way around.

The advantage of this is that client authentication is a transport level protocol, so you don't need to add an additional security layer in the application itself; none of the URL's protected by TLS can be reached. The disadvantage is that you have a more difficult protocol to set up, and that key distribution becomes a bit harder (if you use token authentication as suggested by Henrick, then you will have to distribute the token securily...).

Most application servers should be able to handle client authentication. More information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) under "Client-authenticated TLS handshake".